# Can you use a variable in the outer scope of an anonymous function when there is a name clash?

Tags: java, namespaces, alias, inner-classes

Let's say I have the following interface and class:

```
public interface MessagePrinter {
    public String message = "A message from MessagePrinter!";

    public void printMessage();
}
```

```
public class MessagePrinterCreator {
    public MessagePrinter makeMessagePrinter(final String message) {
        return new MessagePrinter() {
            @Override
            public void printMessage() {
                System.out.println(message);
            }   
        };  
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MessagePrinterCreator myMessagePrinterCreator = new MessagePrinterCreator();
        MessagePrinter m = myMessagePrinterCreator.makeMessagePrinter("A custom message!");
        m.printMessage();
    }   
}
```

The program will output "A message from MessagePrinter!".  Is there any way to get the anonymous class to use the variable "message" from the method "makeMessagePrinter" instead of the variable "message" from the interface "MessagePrinter" so that the output is "A custom message!" without renaming one of the variables?

I realize this is a contrived example; just wondering if it is possible.

Comment: Err, no. Using a different name for the message parameter is the only way. Your local class implements MessagePrinter, which puts 'MessagePrinter' into the class's scope, so 'MessagePrinter.message' hides the 'message' in the outer scope.

Comment: @EJP Seems reasonable.  If you add this as an answer I will accept it.